# UICollectionView Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift2, uicollectionview

**I created my own window in storyboard like below:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeController())
        return true
    }
```

This actually worked fine when my class is subclassing **UIViewController.**

```
class HomeController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Now when I subclass my class with **UICollectionViewController**:

```
class HomeController: UICollectionViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            Collectionview.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


    }
```

At runtime it gives me an error saying:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be
>   initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'
>   *** First throw call stack:

In my understanding it is asking me to give layout for **UICollectionView**.Correct me here if I am wrong.So I tried this-:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeController(UICollectionViewLayout: layout))
        return true
    }
```

But Still ending up with an error:

> Argument labels 'UICollectionViewLayout' do not match any available
>   overloads.

Am I using a wrong **swift3 syntax**? If yes what is correct to solve out this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `UICollectionViewController`'s designated intialiser as below.

```
let layout = UICollectionViewLayout()
let homeViewController = HomeController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController)
```

Along with that, you will need to modify you `HomeViewController` to implement `UICollectionViewDataSource` required methods.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        return 0
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: why can't I use let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout(). UICollectionViewFlowLayout is the built-in layout that subclasses UICollectionViewLayout and is used to implement simple grids. The layout is highly customisable.

Comment: I am using UICollectionViewFlowLayout only in the answer. The name of argument you have used is wrong. It should be HomeController(collectionViewLayout: layout) and not HomeController(UICollectionViewLayout: layout).

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` in `UICollectionViewController`.

Check this [Link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/initWithFrame:collectionViewLayout:)

You must use `initWithFrame:collectionViewLayout:` to initialise your `UICollectionView` and you must pass a non-nil `UICollectionViewLayout object`.